# Find sum of the roots of the equation

Tags: polynomials, roots

How to find the sum of the roots of the following equation:
$\frac{(x+3)^2}{(x+1)^2} + 3\frac{(x+3)}{x+2} - 10\frac{(x+1)^2}{(x+2)^2} = 0$

I have tried a lot of substitutions, but I always end up with 4th degree polynomial. Is there a way to simplify it?

Comment: Yes, you get a quartic polynomial but to get the sum of roots. you only need the coefficients for $x^4$ and $x^3$. In the expansion of your polynomial, you can skip evaluation of those pieces that you don't need. eg $(x+3)^2 (x+2)^2 = x^4+10x^3 + \cdots$

Comment: You might also use technology to find the [**factorization**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factor%28expand%28%28x%2B3%29%5E2%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E2+%2B+3%28x%2B3%29%2F%28x%2B2%29+-+10%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2F%28x%2B2%29%5E2%29%29) and then you can sum the roots of those quadratics. Or use tech to find the [**roots**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=roots%28expand%28%28x%2B3%29%5E2%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E2+%2B+3%28x%2B3%29%2F%28x%2B2%29+-+10%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2F%28x%2B2%29%5E2%29%29) directly.

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-sums-products-roots.html

Answer (score 2):

The sufficient conditions for the equation to be true are $x\neq -1$, and $ x\neq -2$. Expand, and simplify the equation above, and you'll get something like
$$-\frac{6x^4+9x^3-28x^2-71x-44}{(x+1)^2(x+2)^2}=0.$$
Since $x\neq -1$, and $ x\neq -2$, we can get rid of the denominator and obtain
$$6x^4+9x^3-28x^2-71x-44=0.$$
Now, the trick here is to apply [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) and obtain the sum of all complex roots to be
$$r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4=-\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}=-\frac{9}{6}=-\frac{3}{2}.$$
If you want the sum of real roots only then $6x^4+9x^3-28x^2-71x-44$ can be factorized as
$$(x^2-x-4)(6x^2+15x+11),$$
which gives the sum of all real roots to be $1$.